# Cannot get Google Analytics Event tracking to work

Tags: php, html, events, google-analytics, onsubmit

Trying to track a contact form with no separate landing page. Event tracking will not show up in GA. Cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers?

```
<p><input class="submit contact-button" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'colabsthemes'); ?>" onSubmit=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email', 'Submit']);” /></p>
```

Comment: `onSubmit` quotes aren't the usual ones, maybe it's just a copy-paste issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***onsubmit*** needs to go into the ***form*** tag with the right quotes.

You'll also need to make sure that Google Analytics is installed on the form handler page.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the quotes and added to form tag worked like a charm.